# Условие, проверяющее выбранный элемент в списке

Tags: php

Всем привет! Не могу разобраться. Нужно чтоб при выборе в `</option>`, допустим, history проверялась ещё на условие переменная `$predmet` затем сравнивалась и, если это она, в переменную `$page` вносились данные.

```
<?
if ($predmet='history') {($page='vistor');}
if ($predmet='english') {($page='rus');}
?>
<form action="add.php" method="post" name="form">
<select name="predmet" id="predmet">
<option>history</option>
<option>english</option>
<input name="page" type="hidden" value="<? echo $page;?>" />
<p> <input name="add" type="submit" value="Добавить" /></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?
if ($_POST['predmet']=='history') {($page='vistor');}
if ($_POST['predmet']=='english') {($page='rus');}
?>
<form action="add.php" method="post" name="form">
<select name="predmet" id="predmet">
<option value="history">history</option>
<option value="english">english</option>
</select>
<input name="page" type="hidden" value="<?=$page;?>" />
<p> <input name="add" type="submit" value="Добавить" /></p>
</form>
```

**ну и это все в одном файле должно быть- add.php**

хорошо бы еще html разметку подучить, сплошные ошибки!

и вообще непонятно что этот кусок кода вообще делает, масло масленное.

Comment: if ($predmet='history') {($page='vistor');} - это мое неправильно условие ...... 
if ($_POST['predmet']=='history') {($page='vistor');} - вот мое решение    спасибо Вам Shrek !

Comment: пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

двойное равно (==), а не (=) скорее всего нужно использовать, а вообще отформатируете код

Comment: оборачивать `<input />` в `<p>` ИМХО моветон.

не вредно ли оборачивать присваивание в скобки? `($page='value')`

Это все один файл? откуда берется `$predmet`?

на засыпку: `<select>` - имеет закрывающий тег.

Comment: простите <select> - конечно же имеет закрывающий тег